# ETC1 texture opacity

Tags: opengl, glsl, cocos2d-x, blending, alpha-blending

I'm using the cocos2d-x engine and want to support etc1 on android devices for my game.
For ETC1 i'm using the mali compression tool, and GLSL.

Everything is working, but I can't change the opacity of my sprites anymore.

my alpha blending is `GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA` .
can anyone help?

Here are one of my Textures with rgb tex + alpha tex

[image]
[image]

Vertex Shader:

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;
attribute vec4 a_color;


varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying vec2 v_texCoord2;


uniform sampler2D tex1;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = CC_PMatrix * a_position; //CC_PMatrix comes from engine
    v_fragmentColor = a_color;
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
    v_texCoord2 = v_texCoord;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;   
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying vec2 v_texCoord2;

uniform sampler2D u_texture1; //alpha texture


void main()
{
    //CC_Texture0 comes from cocos2d-x engine and represents the rgb
    vec3 tex = texture2D(CC_Texture0, v_texCoord).rgb; 
    float alpha = texture2D(u_texture1, v_texCoord).r;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(tex,alpha);
}
```

Comment: From the Wikipedia description of ETC1: "It does not support the compression of images with Alpha components, although there are work-arounds for this." Are you using [one of these techniques](http://malideveloper.arm.com/develop-for-mali/sample-code/etcv1-texture-compression-and-alpha-channels/) to work around this limitation? If so, which one?

Comment: Yes. I'm using Methode 2

Comment: Can you show us a screengrab, your source textures (RGB & alpha), and the shader code you're using to render them?

Comment: updated my post above